# Python export list of folders & full path as JSON for JSTree

Tags: python, json, jstree

I am trying to create a JSON file for jstree.  But I'm having trouble getting this code to output the full path of the folders and only show folders.  I am new to Python and would appreciate any insight!

The goal is to have users select a folder and bring back the full path of that folder in JSTree.  (Not in this code).

```
import os
import json

def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'text': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
                d['type'] = "directory"
                for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('U:\PROJECTS\MXD_to_PDF'):
                    for directory in directories:
                        d['path']= os.path.join(root, directory)
                d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir\

        (path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
        #del d["type"]

    return d

print json.dumps(path_to_dict('U:\PROJECTS\MXD_to_PDF\TEST'))

with open('U:\PROJECTS\MXD_to_PDF\TEST\JSONData.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(path_to_dict('U:\PROJECTS\MXD_to_PDF\TEST'), f)
```

Output:

```
{
"text": "TEST"
, "type": "directory"
, "children": [{
    "text": "JSONData.json"
    , "type": "file"
}, {
    "text": "Maps"
    , "type": "directory"
    , "children": [{
        "text": "MAY24MODIFIED.mxd"
        , "type": "file"
    }, {
        "text": "MAY24MODIFIED 2016-05-24 16.16.16.pdf"
        , "type": "file"
    }, {
        "text": "testst"
        , "type": "directory"
        , "children": []
        , "path": "U:\\PROJECTS\\MXD_to_PDF\\TEST2\\Maps\\exported"
    }]
    , "path": "U:\\PROJECTS\\MXD_to_PDF\\TEST2\\Maps\\exported"
}]
, "path": "U:\\PROJECTS\\MXD_to_PDF\\TEST2\\Maps\\exported"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following solution works: (you wanted only directories)

```
def get_list_of_dirs(path):
    output_dictonary = {}
    list_of_dirs = [os.path.join(path, item) for item in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item))]
    output_dictonary["text"] = path
    output_dictonary["type"] = "directory"

    output_dictonary["children"] = []

    for dir in list_of_dirs:
        output_dictonary["children"].append(get_list_of_dirs(dir))
    return output_dictonary

print(json.dumps(get_list_of_dirs(path)))
```

(You can insert the import, your path, and saving to file as you wish)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  I have to figure out how you did that!

Comment: Is there anyway to not have the double back slashes?
"U:\\PROJECTS\\MXD_to_PDF\\TEST2"   I see we can add codecs.escape_decode but not sure where to place this?

Comment: That's plattform specific, on windows you have something like you write. I see two options there: 
1. you can play with `os.sep` to replace it with something you want (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)
2. Since at the end the path is just a string, you can use `d["text"].replace("\\", "\")`